# issue with sql request, multiple ID

Tags: mysql

i have this two tables and i need to select everything from **ENT** table and display the name of the skill not the ID.

skill_1, skill_2, skill_3 refer to idSkill from skill table

Thank for you help

**Ent Table :**

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| idEnt | nameEnt | skill_1 | skill_2 | skill_3 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|     1 | testA   |       1 |      2  |      3  |
|     2 | testB   |       4 |      5  |      6  |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Skill Table :**

```
+---------+-------------+
| idSkill |  nameSkill  |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 | Storekeeper |
|       2 | Designer    |
|       3 | Teacher     |
|       4 | Baker       |
|       5 | Gardener    |
|       6 | Secretary   |
+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Have you considered having a separate Ent-Skills table? That way not only would this query be easier, but you would have more flexibility.
I could be wrong, but it seems unlikely that every 'Ent' has exactly 3 skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this table structure you need to join the `skill` table 3 times on `ent` table, every time with different alias:

```
select idEnt, nameEnt, s1.nameSkill as skill1Name, s2.nameSkill as skill2Name, s3.nameSkill as skill3Name
from ent e
inner join skill s1 on e.skill_1=s1.idSkill
inner join skill s2 on e.skill_2=s2.idSkill
inner join skill s3 on e.skill_3=s3.idSkill
```

You may want to consider changing your table structure and have a connection table between `ent` and `skill` tables that hold idEnt - idSkill pairs.

Comment: i'm sorry again, but how can i do if i want to also select the id of the skill for each skill .. ?

Comment: Just simply include that field in the select list. But you should really consider changing the exsisting data structure and create a connector table between your 2 tables. The later you make this change the more difficult it will be.